# How do I use Paypal to sell something and have something in SQL change after the payment is confirmed?

Tags: php, sql, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a website I am making in PHP and I need  to sell an online product.  When someone buys this product I need a way to have my website notified and change some information in an SQL table.  I have googled this for the past five hours and I read things about paypal IPN and paypal sandbox.  I am still very confused about what paypal IPN is and how to use it.  As for paypal sandbox, several tutorials for what I am asking say to use paypal sandbox.  I have tried, but every time I try to login to my account it says the password is wrong, and when I try to make another it redirects me to paypal.com.

My main question is: How do I make buying something on paypal change information in an SQL table on my website?

---

**Update:**

I have been trying to use this tutorial: http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

I have this php code here (modified from the tutorial):

```
    <?php // Database variables
$host = "localhost"; //database location
$user = "user"; //database username
$pass = "pass"; //database password
$db_name = "db"; //database name

// PayPal settings
$paypal_email = 'my sandbox business email is here';
$return_url = 'http://painlessnotes.com/';
$cancel_url = 'http://painlessnotes.com/';
$notify_url = 'http://painlessnotes.com/Paypal/payments.php';

$item_name = 'Test Item';
$item_amount = 10.00;

// Include Functions
include("functions.php");

//Database Connection
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('send start');</script>";

    $querystring = "";

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{$querystring}');</script>";

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();

}else{
    // Response from Paypal
    mail("my email", "response", "TEST", "From: my email is here");//I am using this to check if it works
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    } else {
                mail('my email', '0', '0');//used to check if it works
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
                $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
                if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){
                    $orderid = updatePayments($data);
                    if($orderid){
                        // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database
                    }else{
                        // Error inserting into DB
                        // E-mail admin or alert user
                    }
                }else{
                    // Payment made but data has been changed
                    // E-mail admin or alert user
                }

            }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!
                // E-mail admin or alert user
            }
        }
    fclose ($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

The receiving part of this code works when I use IPN simulator in developer.paypal.com for paypal sandbox.  The functions.php and the html code giving in the tutorial is the same as what is in the tutorial.  When I test this I get the javascript alert boxes coming up and it all looks correct to me, but for some reason I am not getting a response after sending the paypal sandbox request.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?  I have create a buyer with a normal paypal account in the sandbox and a business account.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too broad for SO. Your question needs to be scoped to a specific issue, not an entire "how to". I would suggest you dig deeper into [Paypal developer documentation and resources](https://developer.paypal.com) because they have extensive samples, SDKs for their APIs.

Comment: @EdSF Thank you.  The documentation is confusing.  I added an edit with some code I am trying to make for this, can you take a look and maybe help me make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research and searching I found a paypal page called [Paypal Integration Wizard](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/).

This will generate the code needed for what I have asked.  It gives a step by step process and is easy to follow.  After reading the code I now understand more on how it works.